Could it be that Venus was tidally locked in the past but became retrogradely rotating when got a thick atmosphere?
Could it be possible that when Venus was covered with a CO2 or carbohydrate ocean, it was in tidal lock, but when the ocean evaporated, it started retrograde rotation?
It is known that Venerian atmosphere rotates retrogradely, with much greater speed than the surface, acceerating its rotation.
Why is it so, why the atmosphere accelerates the rotation if ocean usually slows down the rotation due to tidal forces?

Possibly useful: "How does the dense atmosphere of Venus affect the planet's rotation?".

There's no reason to think Venus ever had "a CO2 or carbohydrate ocean".

If we play devil's advocate & suppose Venus might have been tidally locked in its past, a question goes begging. If Venus was ever tidally locked in its past, what was it tidally locked to, what happened to that celestial object & how sudden was the breaking of the tidal lock & what was amount of energy disruption & how did that affect Venus?
